# Filter Pandas Series by Boolean Value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to use Pandas with a JSON object to flatten it, clean up the data, and write it to a relational database.

For any List objects, I want to convert them to a string and create a new column that has a count of the values in the original column.

I've gotten as far as getting a Series of columns which did contain a list. Now I want to filter that list to get back the list of columns that were true. I feel like there should be a straight forward way to filter this Series to only true items but things like filter only seem to work on the index.

```
Current:
d      False
a.b     True
```

```
Desired:
a.b     True
```

My original code:

```
import pandas as _pd
data = {"a":{"b":['x','y','z']},"c":1,"d":None}
df = _pd.json_normalize(data).convert_dtypes()
ldf = df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x,list)).max()
```

Any suggestions on how to easily filter this down to just the true values?

Comment: is `ldf[ldf]` what you want?

Comment: you mean df[ldf]?

Comment: Take a look at [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)